# Sapply on User Defined Function

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions, apply, sapply

What follows is a simplified version of my problem which is much easier to explain than my original one. Assume I have a vector of parameters

`par<-c(0.2,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.9,1,1.2,1.8,1.5)`

and a list called `total` defined as

```
total
[[1]]
[1] 0.2 0.6 0.8 0.3 0.9

[[2]]
[1] 0.2 0.6 0.8 0.3 0.9 0.2 0.8 0.3 0.9 0.2 0.6 0.3 0.9

[[3]]
[1] 0.2 0.6 0.8 0.3 0.9 0.2 0.8 0.3 0.9 0.2 0.6 0.3 0.9
```

Now, lets say that I would like to apply the function `mean` to each one of the 3 elements of the list and each time multiply the result by a function of two parameters selected from `par`. However, the parameters to be selected change with each iteration of `sapply`. For example, when I compute the mean for the 1st element of the list, I want to multiply the result times `sqrt(par[2]*par[3])`, while when calculating the mean of the second element in the `list` I want to multiply the result times `sqrt(par[5]*par[6])`, etc...

I know I can use `sapply` to get the mean of each element in `total` by doing

`sapply(total, mean)`

but how do I tell `sapply` to do the `rolling` multiplication of the result? Should I use `rapply`?

Comment: You don't need that unwieldly lapply/unlist call. Just `sapply(total, mean)`. And it's not really a "rolling" application of anything. You probably should reform your `par` object into a list and use `mapply`.

Comment: Good point, let me correct that!

Comment: What is the rule to traverse your par vector?

Comment: I need to skip one element and then pick the next two. Then skip the next one, and pick the following two and so on... basically pick a pair of consecutive parameters after skipping one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using recyclying you can filter your par vector,  to skip one element and then pick the next two.

```
par <- c(0.2,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.9,1,1.2,1.8,1.5)
xx <- par[c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)]
```

Then `tapply` to split vector xx by each pair and compute the sqrt:

```
 sqrt_xx <-  
 tapply(xx,rep(1:(length(xx)/2),each=2),function(x)sqrt(prod(x))))
```

Then using `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x,y)mean(x)*y, ,total,sqrt_xx)
0.3313005 0.5108295 0.8847826
```

Where total is :

```
dput(total)
list(c(0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.9), c(0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 
0.8, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.9), c(0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.9, 
0.2, 0.8, 0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.9))
```